# Passing enum values from razor files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a "myfile.cs" file and "myview.cshtml" file. The enum are declared in "myfile.cs" file. They are shown in "myview.cshtml" but these values have to go to a "General.js" file and from there to another "PerformSave.cs" file using .post method.

So i want to pass int value in . For example i want to pass PerformSave(1) for "France". any ideas how can I do that?

```
myfile.cs
namespace mynamespace.Models
{
public enum country
{
   England,  // 0
   France,   // 1
   Germany   // 2
 }

 public country CustCountry { get; set; }
 ...

 }

my.cshtml
<button id="Save" class="button">Save</button><br>
<script>
      $("#Save").click(function () {
      PerformSave(@Model.CustCountry);
      }
</script>

general.js
PerformSave: function (country) {
  $.post(URL , { country },function (data,status, xhr) {

  }
}
```

Comment: Not clear what your wanting to do. How do you render a control(s) for property `CustCountry`? What is the controller method that you want to post back to. Note `@Model.CustCountry` will post back the original value, not a value that has been modified in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I guess somewhere you have a dropdown from which you can select Countries. Having the String from Country, cast it to CountryEnum and then back to int.

From String to Enum:

```
var country = (CountryEnum) Enum.Parse( typeof(CountryEnum), "France", true );
```

From Enum to Int:

```
var value = (int) country;
```

Now value will have country's ID